# When does the Special Price “To Date” actually expire?

Tags: price, date

My client is having a Black Friday sale from 11/29/13 to 12/2/2013. Do I need to select 12/2/2013 or 12/3/2013 for it still be showing on 12/2/2013 but not 12/3/2013?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Try it.
Create a coupon (or rule) with the expiration data 'today' and see if it's available.

And to answer the question, the expiration date is included in the validity period.
So in your case it should be `12/2/2013`.